# Polynomial inequality for imaginary roots

Tags: inequality, polynomials, roots

I've to solve the following polynomial inequality

$$x^2 - 6x + 11 > 0$$
By using quadratic formula, I got the value of $x$ as below

$$ \frac{6\pm \sqrt{-8}}{2}$$

These are imaginary roots and the graph will never touch 
$x$-axis.  So, I'm not sure what would be the solution set for $x$? Is it something like $$\{x | −\infty  < x < +\infty \}$$

Comment: I suggest you plot the polynomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When solving equations you need to state the domain of $x$. If your problem is over the complex numbers, then the solution set is as you have given:
$$x = 3 \pm i \sqrt{2}.$$

If your problem requires $x$ to be a real number then you have shown that there are no such solutions to this equation. In this case the solution set for $x$ is the empty set $\{\emptyset \}$.

One would say "there are no *real* solutions to this equation."
You might like to look up the fundamental theorem of algebra for polynomial equations of order $N$ over the complex numbers...

Anyway, since you see that the graph of your polynomial is always above the x axis, as we've shown that there are no real solutions, then any value of x will satisfy the equality. Thus the solution is $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It's probably safe to assume that $x$ is taken to be real, as there is no standard ordering $<$ on $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Correct - I wished only to clarify the nature of the critical values of x for the op

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2-6x+11>0$$
$$x^2-6x+9+2>0$$
$$(x-3)^2+2>0$$
because $$(x-3)^2\geq 0 ,\space\forall x\in\mathbb R$$

Comment: I've not seen this `0 ∀x` in my Math course so far. I'm not sure what does it mean?

Comment: follow this link [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)]